# How to: C# WebClient to hit service endpoint (Oauth 2.0 like protocol) with Mutual TLS

Tags: c#, oauth, ssl-certificate, restsharp

I need to hit a service to obtain the app ticket to authenticate against another service. The solution is hosted on a endpoint.

I tried using the POSTMAN app in google chrome and it succeeds and returns me the AppID. When I submit the (POST)request in POSTMAN app, it prompts for a certificate. When I select the correct certificate the call succeeds.

I need to implement the same in C# (in a web application)

I tried using the RestSharp.RestClient library and am constantly getting the following error:
"Client certificate not found in site certificates".

Attaching the code for reference.

---

```
var client = new RestSharp.RestClient("MyUrl");

var request = new RestSharp.RestRequest("pksecure/oauth20_clientcredentials.srf", RestSharp.Method.POST);
request.AddParameter("grant_type", "client_credentials");
request.AddParameter("param2", "value2");
request.AddParameter("scope", "machinename");

client.ClientCertificates = new System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509CertificateCollection();
client.ClientCertificates.Add(new System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate(
    @"E:\MyCertificate.pfx"
    , "MyPassword"
    ));

System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
        delegate(object sender, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate cert, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain chain, System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors sslError)
        {
            bool validationResult = true;
            return validationResult;
        };


var response = client.Execute(request);
var content = response.Content; // raw content as string
```

---

Pls. help to make this call using the mutual TLS.

TIA,
Sam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why I was not able to get it done using **RestSharp**.

But I could get it working by using **HttpWebRequest** Instead.

Also, earlier I was using the *Certficate.Pfx* file which caused the error. Using the *Certificate.Cer* file solved the issue.

Posting the code for reference:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("MyURL/oauth20_clientcredentials.srf");

var postData = "grant_type=client_credentials";
postData += "&param2=value2";
postData += "&scope=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("machinename");
var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);

request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.ContentLength = data.Length;

using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
}

request.ClientCertificates.Add(new System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate(@"E:\MyCertificate.cer"));

var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

return appToken;
```

Thanks,

Sam Jayander Thiagarajan.